# How to display text in LWJGL using version 3.2 or above

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

I've been using the [lwjgl wiki](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) to learn about how to use the library, and I've been setting up LWJGL with the following (as per [this tutorial](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Version_selection)):

```
PixelFormat pixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
ContextAttribs contextAttributes = new ContextAttribs(3, 2)
                                       .withForwardCompatible(true)
                                       .withProfileCore(true);
Display.setTitle("Title");
try
{
    Display.setFullscreen(true);
    Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
    Display.create(pixelFormat, contextAttributes);
}
catch(LWJGLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

glViewport(0, 0, sizeX, sizeY);
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

[Another tutorial](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_3_-_TrueType_Fonts_for_LWJGL) explains how to draw text. However, TrueTypeFont is deprecated so I replaced it with the now standard UnicodeFont. I Initialize and use it like this:

```
UnicodeFont font = null;
try
{
    font = new UnicodeFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
                              new File("path/to/font.ttf")).deriveFont(24)));
}
catch (FontFormatException | IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

while(true)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    font.drawString(50.0f, 50.0f, "Hi there.",
                           new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
}
```

This generates the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glColor4f(GL11.java:881)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.renderer.ImmediateModeOGLRenderer.glColor4f(ImmediateModeOGLRenderer.java:119)
at org.newdawn.slick.Color.bind(Color.java:180)
at org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont.drawString(TrueTypeFont.java:367)
at org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont.drawString(TrueTypeFont.java:359)
```

at the line where drawString is called. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an OpenGL 3.2 forward compatible context, but apparently the font renderer is using immediate mode rendering, which is removed from that version of OpenGL. Either create a compatibility context or switch to some other method of rendering fonts.